# Circular Nonconsecutive Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A carousel has eight seats, each representing a different animal. Eight girls are seated on the carousel facing forward (each girl looks at another girl's back). In how many ways can the girls change seats so that each has a different girl in front of her? How does the problem change if all seats are identical?

Because the carousel seats are all different animals it means they are distinguishable so I can't just use the following equation

$$C(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k-1)!+(-1)^n$$

I know it doesn't become a linear permutation because we will still have n patterns.

If the seats were identical- it would be a circular permutation problem and I could use the equation from above.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $P$ be the set of acceptable circular permutations when the seats are identical; you know how to calculate $|P|$. Each $\pi\in P$ corresponds to $8$ acceptable rearrangements in the original problem, and each acceptable rearrangement in the original problem represents one of the permutations in $P$.